# dplyr - mutate and count in the same pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I have the following data frame:

```
D = data_frame(gender = c("M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F"), age = c(20, 33, 42, 32, 
55, 70, 18, 22, 30, 40))
```

I would like to **both** count the genders, and calculate the mean age of each.

I have tried:

```
D %>% group_by(gender) %>% mutate(M = mean(age)) %>% count()
```

But this gets rid of the mean age already calculated.
Seems like it should be an easy task... what am I missing?

Comment: `D %>% group_by(gender) %>% summarise(M = mean(age), cnt = n())` probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help file of `count()` says :

> tally() is a convenient wrapper for summarise that will either call n() or sum(n) depending on whether you're tallying for the first time, or re-tallying. count() is similar but calls group_by() before and ungroup() after.

So let's use `summarize()` with `n()` :

```
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
D <-tibble(gender = c("M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F"), 
           age = c(20, 33, 42, 32, 55, 70, 18, 22, 30, 40))
D %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  summarize(n = n(), mean_age = mean(age))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   gender     n mean_age
#>   <chr>  <int>    <dbl>
#> 1 F          6     41.5
#> 2 M          4     28.2
```